# PHP mail function not sending email (php.ini and sendmail.ini are both configured)

Tags: php, xampp, smtp, localhost

In order to work with the php mail function i configured both php.ini and sendmail.ini, by commenting all the code in the [mail function] in php.ini and pasting the following code:

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = ******@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

and did the same in the sendmail.ini file:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=******@gmail.com
auth_password=*******
force_sender=*******@gmail.com
```

After that, the following error stopped raising :

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

but the mail function still don't work and displays the "Error" string as i specified in the else statement is the following code :

```
<?php
$sub = "TEST";
$msg = "Sent";
$rec = "*******@gmail.com";
 if(mail($rec,$sub,$msg)){
    echo "email sent";
 }else{
    echo "Error";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Did you restart the webserver after updating php.ini?

Comment: Have you configured in App Password on your gmail account?

Comment: @Barmar yeah i i tried restarting apache and xampp but nothing new happens

Comment: Use app passwords

Comment: @ADyson I have just generated an App Password and paste it in auth_password in sendmail.ini file and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Probably worth writing that up as a proper Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the mail function, you need to generate an App password and assign  it to auth_password in the sendmail.ini file. Here's the process:

1-Go to your Google Account.

2-Click on "Security".

3-Enable "2-step verification", then click  the "App Password" section.

4-From the "Select app" dropdown, choose "Mail", and from the "Select 
device" dropdown, select "Other (Custom name)".

5-Give the app a descriptive name, such as "Mail Client".

6-Click "Generate".

7-Copy the generated App Password.

8-Paste the password as the value for auth_password in the sendmail.ini file.